# virtualbox GUI in FreeBSD

Tags: virtualbox, freebsd

I have a problem with virtualbox-ose port in freebsd.

```
ns387352# make install clean
===>  virtualbox-ose-4.0.12 is marked as broken: QT4 frontend requires X11 support. Run 'make config' again!.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/emulators/virtualbox-ose.
```

qt4 is installed, xorg is installed, what else is wrong??

Comment: Did you run *make config*?

Comment: "make config" just gives you window of options where qt4 and x11 already checked..

Comment: @holms: is there a way to solve this problem: http://superuser.com/questions/1160185/error-when-trying-to-install-virtualbox-ose-additions-in-freebsd-as-a-guest-on-v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's condition in Makefile:

```
.if defined(WITHOUT_X11) && !defined(WITHOUT_QT4)
BROKEN=QT4 frontend requires X11 support. Run 'make config' again!.
.endif
```

so check your configuration, make.conf, src.conf again!

Comment: yeah WITHOUT_X11=true was set.