# Error when trying to install virtualbox-ose-additions in FreeBSD as a Guest on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, freebsd

After installing FreeBSD 11 using latest virtual box software and setting up gnome3 along with Xorg, all was fine, but when I tried to install [virtualbox-ose-additions](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/virtualization-guest-virtualbox.html) using Virtual Box, I'm facing the following error:

[image]

And here is the complete output:

```
$ pwd
/usr/ports/emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions
$ sudo make -j 4
Password:
--- stage ---
--- /usr/ports/emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions/work/.patch_done.virtualbox-ose._usr_local ------ build-depends ---
===>   virtualbox-ose-additions-4.3.38 depends on executable: yasm - found
===>   virtualbox-ose-additions-4.3.38 depends on executable: kmk - found
===>   virtualbox-ose-additions-4.3.38 depends on file: /usr/local/bin/X - found
===>   virtualbox-ose-additions-4.3.38 depends on package: libiconv>=1.14_9 - found
===>   virtualbox-ose-additions-4.3.38 depends on file: /usr/local/bin/python2.7 - found
===>   virtualbox-ose-additions-4.3.38 depends on package: pkgconf>=0.9.10 - found
===>   virtualbox-ose-additions-4.3.38 depends on package: libGL>0 - found
===>   virtualbox-ose-additions-4.3.38 depends on file:   /usr/local/libdata/pkgconfig/inputproto.pc - found
===>   virtualbox-ose-additions-4.3.38 depends on file: /usr/local/libdata/pkgconfig/glproto.pc - found
===>   virtualbox-ose-additions-4.3.38 depends on file: /usr/local/libdata/pkgconfig/dri2proto.pc - found
===>   virtualbox-ose-additions-4.3.38 depends on file: /usr/local/libdata/pkgconfig/xcursor.pc - found
===>   virtualbox-ose-additions-4.3.38 depends on file: /usr/local/libdata/pkgconfig/xmu.pc - found
===>   virtualbox-ose-additions-4.3.38 depends on file: /usr/local/libdata/pkgconfig/xorg-server.pc - found
===>   virtualbox-ose-additions-4.3.38 depends on file: /usr/local/libdata/pkgconfig/xrandr.pc - found
`lib-depends' was not built (made 1, flags 2019, type b410001)!
`lib-depends' has .ORDER dependency against run-depends (made 1, flags 9, type b410001)
`lib-depends' has .ORDER dependency against run-depends (made 1, flags 9, type b410001)
`configure-message' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`configure-message' has .ORDER dependency against lib-depends (made 1, flags 2019, type b410001)
`run-autotools-fixup' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`run-autotools-fixup' has .ORDER dependency against configure-message (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)
`do-configure' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`do-configure' has .ORDER dependency against run-autotools-fixup (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)
`build-message' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`build-message' has .ORDER dependency against configure (made 1, flags 3009, type 3010001)
`pre-build' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`pre-build' has .ORDER dependency against build-message (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)
`do-build' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`do-build' has .ORDER dependency against pre-build (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)
`stage-message' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`stage-message' has .ORDER dependency against build (made 1, flags 3009, type 3010001)
`stage-dir' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`stage-dir' has .ORDER dependency against stage-message (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)
`run-depends' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b410001)!
`run-depends' has .ORDER dependency against stage-dir (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)
`apply-slist' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`apply-slist' has .ORDER dependency against lib-depends (made 1, flags 2019, type b410001)
`/usr/ports/emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions/work/stage/boot/modules' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`/usr/ports/emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions/work/stage/boot/modules' has .ORDER dependency against apply-slist (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)
`/usr/ports/emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions/work' was not built (made 0, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`do-install' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`do-install' has .ORDER dependency against generate-plist (made 1, flags 3009, type b010001)
`compress-man' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`compress-man' has .ORDER dependency against do-install (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)
`install-rc-script' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`install-rc-script' has .ORDER dependency against compress-man (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)
`install-ldconfig-file' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type 3010001)!
`install-ldconfig-file' has .ORDER dependency against install-rc-script (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)
`install-license' was not built (made 1, flags 2009, type b010001)!
`install-license' has .ORDER dependency against install-ldconfig-file (made 1, flags 2009, type 3010001)
*** [stage] Error code 1

make: stopped in /usr/ports/emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions
1 error

make: stopped in /usr/ports/emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions
$
```

**Just found a second method --> install by package:**

```
$ pkg install emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions
```

but I have this error again:

```
$ sudo pkg install emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions
Password:
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
Updating database digests format: 100%
The following 1 package(s) will be affected (of 0 checked):

New packages to be INSTALLED:
    virtualbox-ose-additions: 5.1.6_1

Number of packages to be installed: 1

The process will require 3 MiB more space.
592 KiB to be downloaded.

Proceed with this action? [y/N]: y
Fetching virtualbox-ose-additions-5.1.6_1.txz: 100%  589 KiB 603.4kB/s    00:01    
pkg: cached package virtualbox-ose-additions-5.1.6_1: size mismatch,     fetching from remote
Fetching virtualbox-ose-additions-5.1.6_1.txz: 100%  589 KiB 603.4kB/s    00:01    
pkg: cached package virtualbox-ose-additions-5.1.6_1: size mismatch, cannot continue
```

Trying **pkg install virtualbox-ose (www.freshports.org/emulators/virtualbox-ose/)** not working too:

```
$ sudo pkg install virtualbox-ose
Password:
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
The following 5 package(s) will be affected (of 0 checked):

New packages to be INSTALLED:
    virtualbox-ose: 5.1.6_1
    libvncserver: 0.9.10_1
    virtualbox-ose-kmod: 5.1.6
    qt5-opengl: 5.6.1
    qt5-printsupport: 5.6.1

Number of packages to be installed: 5

The process will require 335 MiB more space.
55 MiB to be downloaded.

Proceed with this action? [y/N]: y
Fetching virtualbox-ose-5.1.6_1.txz: 100%   54 MiB 792.7kB/s    01:12    
pkg: cached package virtualbox-ose-5.1.6_1: size mismatch, fetching from remote
Fetching virtualbox-ose-5.1.6_1.txz: 100%   54 MiB   2.9MB/s    00:20    
pkg: cached package virtualbox-ose-5.1.6_1: size mismatch, cannot continue
$
```

After some research about those errors I didn't find something talking about.

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

I'm using virtual box 5.1.12 r112440

Thanks.